# REST strict validation or not?

Tags: json, api, rest

I'm using Java spring boot microservices that uses the Jackson json parser. In regards to json schemas that i define in my open api specification I've noticed that my implementation will allow fields over and above what is defined in my schema through....

i.e.
My schema currently allows for:

```
{
    "Name": "Denu",
    "Contact": 12345678
}
```

My code does not fail when I provide the blah property as per below. It simply ignores it:

```
{
    "Name": "Denu",
    "Contact": 12345678,
    "blah": "example"
}
```

I can change this using strict validation which can be configured for the Jackson parser but I want to know from an industry standard point of view is there any reference standard documented to whether i should go with strict or not?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My schema currently allows...

If you are in a context where you need the option to *extend* the schema, then you will want to be considering design principles like "must ignore" and "must forward".

See, for example [David Orchard 2003](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/03/versioning.html); the concepts then applied to XML schema designs are still useful when designing a JSON schema.

Other useful references:

- [David Orchard 2004](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/10/27/extend.html)
- [Mike Amundsen 2017](http://amundsen.com/talks/2017-03-sxsw/2017-03-sxsw-patterns.pdf)